# Get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error  in Chrome console in the script below. Specifically, it looks like there is problem in the line 12. If anyone have solution to get it fixed, would appreciate much. Thanks in advance!
P.S: Please check the HTML for it here: https://jsbin.com/jojufiqibu/edit?html,js,output

```
function countChecked() {
  var NUM_QUESTIONS = 26;

  var count = 0; //tracks the number of checked off radio groups
  var total = 0; //tracks the number of correct answers

  //insert a null at Array[0] so tune number matches index number
  correctTunes = new Array(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0);

  //start at 1 so tune number matches index number
  for (var i = 1; i <= NUM_QUESTIONS; i++) {
   var isYesChecked = eval("document.forms[0].correct"+i+"[0].checked");
   var isNoChecked = eval("document.forms[0].correct"+i+"[1].checked");

   //as long as one of these values is true, the group is checked
   if (isYesChecked || isNoChecked) {
    count++;
   }

   //if isYesChecked matches the corresponding array value, the answer is correct
   if (correctTunes[i] == isYesChecked) {
    total++;
   }
  }

  //if count doesn't match, at least one group isn't checked;
  //must use NaN and not "false" since 0 is a valid returnable number
  if (count < NUM_QUESTIONS) {
   return NaN;
  }

  //returns the number of correct answers, which also doubles as "return true"
  return total;
 }
```

Comment: Seems like the structure of your form is different from what you think it is. It seems there is no form control element with name `control0` or `control1`.

Comment: debug, and determine what is undefined!

Comment: A) **Don't use eval willy-nilly** - it has it purpose, but this is not it. B) Because we cannot see the value `document.forms[0].correct"+i+"[0].checked`, we cannot help. Also, _don't use eval_.

Comment: Why, for the love of god, are you using eval for that?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just seen youve posted your html in a comment - your html does not have any `form` elements, hence `document.forms[0]` will be undefined.

---

In general, the error `“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined”` comes about when you try to access a variable whose value is `undefined` using an array-like square bracket syntax.

The code below demonstrates this in a rather convoluted way (Setting up a function with a parameter, only to call the function without passing an argument, making that parameter `undefined`. Watch the console for the error)

```js
function doSomething(myArray){
   console.log(myArray[0]); 
}

doSomething();
```

Now, in your code this really only boils down to 1 thing, either `document.forms` is `undefined` or on one of the iterations of your loop `document.forms[0].correctX` is undefined (where `X` is a value from your loop).

Without seeing your HTML, it is impossible to ascertain what exactly is happening, but you can debug it by stepping through until the error is occurred and looking at the value of `i`.

---

As an aside, and has been mentioned in comments `eval` is unnecessary here, you can use the square bracket notation to dynamically access objects, and this may also help you debug:

```
var isYesChecked = document.forms[0]["correct"+i][0].checked;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. If i can't use document.forms[0] since i don't have forms, could you please specify how my script should look like. Sorry, i'm newbie in JS.

Comment: Just wrap your html with a  `<form>`  tag, and you'll have access to `document.forms[0]` with no problem. Other things are if you experiment another kind of problems, but the thing you are asking solves writing at least one form tag.